# Using conditional operator inside Element.classList.add()

Tags: javascript, svelte, conditional-operator

I'm making an application that uses TypeScript, and as a templating language I'm using Svelte.

That allows me to create DOM elements with classes that can change in realtime according to a variable, thanks to ternary operator. For instance:

```
<div class="{theme == "dark" ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}"> Hello </div>
```

The thing is, my application has to dynamically generate some DOM elements. That makes me create some `div`s using the following piece of script:

```
const parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
const childDiv = document.createElement("div")
childDiv.classList.add(theme == "dark" ? "bg-black" : "bg-white")
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv)
```

In this case, the conditional operator is just calculated when `.add()` is called, which happens once. There is no "realtime calculation" of the value like in the first method above. How do I handle this ?

Comment: can you please better explain what do you expect the code to do?

Comment: also try to put the calculation of the `theme` variable before the classList.add() method like: ```let bg = theme === "dark ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"```

Comment: Instead of creating the `div`s like that, create them dynamically via Svelte. When or based on what are new elements added?

Comment: I would look at an inline instance to mimic: https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/5y794fjv/

Comment: @Armando_pagano I expect the class to change when the variable theme changes. Your proposition does not solve the problem as the class will always be equal to the value at the creation of the item. I want it to listen to the theme variable for the lifetime of the application is running

Comment: @Corrl the new element is added when a button is clicked. Creating the div dynamically with svelte is not an option it has to be .add() like in the question

Comment: Svelte has a context where it controls elements it knows about. What you're showing are just a dom element you're creating and adding to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not creating the elements via plain Svelte markup you are probably doing something wrong. There are various directives that help, e.g. `{#if}` and `{#each}`.

In some cases it makes sense to imperatively add things, but even then, you should add *components* not plain DOM elements. You can instantiate any component using the [client API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api), e.g.

```js
new MyComponent({ target: document.body })
```

Anything inside the component then can use the Svelte mechanism that automatically update. If you need to have reactivity from the outside, you can pass a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) as a property or import a global store from within/load it from a context.

(Would recommend making the theme a store. Either global or passed through props/contexts.)

---

Note on contexts with the client API: They have to be passed explicitly; to inherit existing contexts you can use [`getAllContexts`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getallcontexts):

```js
// somewhere at top-level
const context = getAllContexts();
// ...
new MyComponent({ ..., context })
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution to my problem, however if MyComponent exports an attribute, how do I specify a value for this attribute using the new MyComponent syntax ?

Comment: Please see the linked docs (also they are called props).